# How do I track users and installations on the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, analytics, chrome-web-store

I developed a Chrome extension called [TabCarousel](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ddldimidiliclngjipajmjjiakhbcohn) to help monitor information like our NewRelic graphs.  After realizing other people might find it useful, I decided to [open source it](http://github.com/benjaminoakes/TabCarousel) and then release it on the [Chrome Web Store](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ddldimidiliclngjipajmjjiakhbcohn).

I'm really impressed with how easy it is to release code on the Web Store, but... even a couple days after the extension has been released, I still show " users" and " weekly installs" rather than something like "7 users" and "10 weekly installs".  I know I've set my extension up on a few computers, and I've helped others set it up as well.  A few friends have installed it too.

Why doesn't the Chrome Web Store show **any** users or installations?  It's not showing any data at all -- that is, " users" instead of "0 users".

Am I just missing something?  I've read through the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/faq.html), some [blog posts](http://petelepage.com/blog/2011/06/the-anatomy-of-a-great-chrome-web-store-listing/), and even set up a Google Analytics account and entered it in the Developer Dashboard entry for my extension.  I just want to get an idea of how many downloads I'm getting so I can gauge interest like I can [on other projects](http://rubygems.org/gems/maid).

Comment: This is actually a bug, it is in the process of being fixed and pushed.

Comment: @Kinlan From looking at your profile, I'm guessing that's a pretty authoritative answer.  I'm starting to see some data now.  Could you make your comment an answer so I can upvote and accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a bug, and the team are in the process of preparing a fix and getting it pushed live.  I don't have an exact ETA, but it should be pretty soon.

On another note, you can still use your Google Analytics accounts to detect traffic to your landing page and in your app.  And if you look for the referrer chrome://newtab you will get a very good indication of all the users who are launching your app.

Comment: Interesting. It's been that way since as long as I can remember, and I always figured the week-or-so delay was deliberate. Nice to know.

Comment: It has been daily in the past, If you go back it looks like things started to stop on the 15th of June.

Comment: It looks like everything is catching up now, I just checked https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lkmdeepeooimedpakfaiahicgilkifef which was affected but now has user numbers.

Comment: I just started toying with the Chrome Web Store, and currently my Apache access logs show an empty referer when I open a new tab in Chrome and click on my app's icon. Has there been a deliberate change, or did I get this all wrong?

Comment: I love it when teams support their product on StackOverflow!  Thanks @Kinlan and Google Chrome team!

Answer (score 1):

Just give it few days, they don't update counters in WebStore too often. Currently it doesn't show users for any extension submitted after June 15, and yours was submitted on June 19.

Comment: This bug is being fixed and should be live soon.

Comment: I don't know what "soon" means to you @Kinlan, but I doubt it's a bug since it hasn't been fixed over the last year. I guess it's on purpose it only updates every now and then.

Comment: @MariusHaugenEngen this was fixed ages ago, updates only happen daily

Comment: @Kinlan ah, yes. I noticed. It took two days before I got any stats, but now it's updated daily :)